# li onclick function not getting called

Tags: javascript, html

I have trouble calling the onclick function inside the li element.when I put a url to the href it works fine. But I want to call a javascript function through onclick .Any help is appreciated.

```js
function display_s(){
 alert("success");
 }
```

```html
<div style="" class="icon_bar">
   <ul style="padding:0 ; margin : 0;display:flex; justify-content: center;">
      <li  onclick="display_specs()">
         <a href="#" >
            <div style="display:flex;align-items:center;flex-direction:column">
               <div style="height:35px;width:35px;padding:5px"> <img src="/static/phone.bmp" style="max-width:100%;height:auto"></div>
               <div style="padding:5px"  > Mobile</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is typo in function name

Comment: check the name of the function `display_specs` -> `display_s`

Comment: Typo i corrected.Still the issue is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to what I type. You have some type error.

```js
function display_specs(){
 alert("success");
 }
```

```html
<div style="" class="icon_bar">
   <ul style="padding:0 ; margin : 0;display:flex; justify-content: center;">
      <li  onclick="display_specs()">
         <a href="#" >
            <div style="display:flex;align-items:center;flex-direction:column">
               <div style="height:35px;width:35px;padding:5px"> <img src="/static/phone.bmp" style="max-width:100%;height:auto"></div>
               <div style="padding:5px"  > Mobile</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In your html, you call display_specs(). But in your js file, you defined display_s(). That's the problem.

Comment: Did you try to run the sniipest in my answer? I can see the alert.

Answer (score 2):

You're onclickfucntion name and in `script` tag name must be same like that. Also if you wanna learn more information about `onClick` you can check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

```js
function display_specs(){
 alert("success");
 }
```

```html
<div style="" class="icon_bar">
   <ul style="padding:0 ; margin : 0;display:flex; justify-content: center;">
      <li  onclick="display_specs()">
         <a href="#" >
            <div style="display:flex;align-items:center;flex-direction:column">
               <div style="height:35px;width:35px;padding:5px"> <img src="/static/phone.bmp" style="max-width:100%;height:auto"></div>
               <div style="padding:5px"  > Mobile</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Call the function in li and it will work.
<script>
function display_s()
{
    alert('check');return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="" class="icon_bar">
   <ul style="padding:0 ; margin : 0;display:flex; justify-content: center;">
        <li  onclick="display_s()" style="cursor:pointer"></li>


   </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You are calling to the wrong function which is not defined. when you are click on
>   `li` you should call to the function `display_s()`.

```js
function display_s(){
 alert("success");
 }
```

```html
<div style="" class="icon_bar">
   <ul style="padding:0 ; margin : 0;display:flex; justify-content: center;">
      <li  onclick="display_s()">
         <a href="#" >
            <div style="display:flex;align-items:center;flex-direction:column">
               <div style="height:35px;width:35px;padding:5px"> <img src="/static/phone.bmp" style="max-width:100%;height:auto"></div>
               <div style="padding:5px"  > Mobile</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```